# Combining parallax scrolling with a "mouse tracker"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a page that needs to have two effects:

1. Parallax scrolling
2. An "effect" that follows the mouse around on screen.

I've taken examples from other code bits and fiddles to get the general idea of what needs to happen, but there's a problem with the mouse effect. Here's my code so far (note that some of it may be redundant or obsolete, I've been ruinning lots of tests with this):

```js
$("#imageholder").on("mousemove", function(e){
  var ofst = ($(window).width() - 1024)/2;
  $("#glass").css({
    left :  Math.round(e.pageX - 60 - ofst) + "px",
    top : Math.round(e.pageY - 60 )  + "px"
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);

html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 perspective: 1px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Nunito;

}

h1 {
   font-size: 250%
}

p {
  font-size: 140%;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333;

}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25vh 10%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;

 transform-style: inherit;
  
}



.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(218,165,32, .7);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(102,102,102,1) 33%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 45%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 46%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 19%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 58%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 71%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 64%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); 
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.slide, .slide:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;  
}



#title {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
   background-attachment: fixed;  
}

#slide3:before {
  //CAN USE IMAGE OR GRADIENT BG!
  //background-image: url("http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/9iz/obB/9izobBr4T.jpeg");
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(218,165,32,0)60%,rgba(218,165,32,1) 100%);
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index:-1;
}


#imageholder {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#glass {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
}
#glass:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  content: "";
background: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  z-index: 898;
  zoom:1.1;
}
#glass:after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  content:"";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background:blue;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: 889;
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px) saturate(120%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageholder">
<div id="slide3" class="slide">

  <div class="title">


    <h1>Title</h1> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
   

  <div id="glass"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem I've encountered is that the parallax is also having an effect on the "glass" that should be tracking the mouse. If this code were working, wherever you moved your mouse the "glass" would be on top of it.

Is it a problem I can fix with some JQuery, or is it the CSS I should modify to fix this?

Comment: I think it'll be a combination. Try moving the glass div outside of the parallax scroll. Change the position type to "fixed" or "absolute", and have the mouse relative position using the glass's new container (for absolute) of the screen (for fixed). Also, maybe limit the perspective transform on the inner element instead of the entire body.

Comment: With what you advised I came up with this revision, but now I cannot scroll at all. I believe this is because I'm trapped inside the "glass" div and can't focus anywhere else.

https://jsfiddle.net/pfheLz7k/1/

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I messed with the Z-index and got it to work better. If I can get the code to work from here I will mark you as the "Solution" and offer my findings.

Comment: Odd, I can scroll fine in that fiddle you provided.

Comment: I think I fixed it, see the edit to my comment above. I'm going to keep playing with it and see what becomes of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something a bit like this?

Moved the glass div element to the body.

Move the rest of the elements (excluding glass) to another div with class "parallax".

Apply parallax effect to above div only.

Change mousemove event to document level.

P.S. Not sure what you want with the offset, so I remove it for now to demostrate how the glass can track the mouse exactly.

```js
$(document).on("mousemove", function(e){
  $("#glass").css({
    left :  Math.round(e.pageX - 60) + "px",
    top : Math.round(e.pageY -60)  + "px"
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);

html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Nunito;
}
.parallax{
 perspective: 1px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
h1 {
   font-size: 250%
}

p {
  font-size: 140%;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333;

}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25vh 10%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;

 transform-style: inherit;
  
}



.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(218,165,32, .7);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%,rgba(102,102,102,1) 33%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 45%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 46%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 19%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 58%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 71%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 64%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); 
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.slide, .slide:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;  
}



#title {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
   background-attachment: fixed;  
}

#slide3:before {
  //CAN USE IMAGE OR GRADIENT BG!
  //background-image: url("http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/9iz/obB/9izobBr4T.jpeg");
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(218,165,32,0)60%,rgba(218,165,32,1) 100%);
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index:-1;
}


#imageholder {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#glass {
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
}
#glass:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  content: "";
background: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  z-index: 898;
  zoom:1.1;
}
#glass:after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  content:"";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background:blue;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: 889;
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px) saturate(120%);
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax">
    <div id="imageholder">
    <div id="slide3" class="slide">

      <div class="title">


        <h1>Title</h1> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
      </div>
       

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div id="glass"></div>
```